# Django Template goes to relative url when hyperlinked

Tags: html, django-templates

Hi I have a Django Model like below

```
class Staff(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    url = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

URL's are generated from another website and they are like in the databse

```
www.foo.com/xxx-yyy

www.foo.com/xxx-zzz
```

When I use a django template like below, link goes to a related url like an extension of my current URL

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% load markup %}
{% block right %}
<h1>Names</h1>
{% for i in persons %}
<p><a href="http://{{i.url}}">{{i.name}}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

It goes to **mycurrent.url.com/www.foo.com/xxx-yyy**

Answer (score 0):

Ok it is fixed by adding http:// before 
like;

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% load markup %}
{% block right %}
<h1>Names</h1>
{% for i in persons %}
<p><a href="http://{{i.url}}">{{i.name}}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```